# Bitly API authentication for links analytics of other users

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, bit.ly

I would like to grab the number of clicks for an arbitrary bitly link - not just those links that I created. Is this possible through the bitly API? And if so, what's the process to get the correct access_token. I've tried using the generic one you can generate on the site, but that only works for my own links.
Thank you!
Ren

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get click data on arbitrary bitly links using the [clicks](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks) endpoint. You can try it out with the [API Console](http://dev.bitly.com/console.html) with a few different bitly links and see how if you run into problems.

To get an access token for just your account, you can follow the steps at the very top of [the authentication docs](http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html).